# How to invoke multiple selenium scripts one after the other without using '@Beforetest' and '@Aftertest' functionalities

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have written few selenium web driver codes in eclipse for testing various functionalities of a web application. 
I wish to invoke them one after the other. 
But I do not want to merge them into a single code using the '@Beforetest' and '@Aftertest' functionalities, as depending on the requirement, I might have to run individual tests as well.
So can anyone suggest a way so I could invoke them all by just changing the dependencies in .xml file?

Comment: I didn't quite catch what are You actually trying to achieve? Are You trying to say that You would like to have multiple classes which will have @Before and "@AfterTest" in one place, so You don't have repetitive tests? And I don't get this part "I could invoke them all by just changing the dependencies in .xml file"? Could You please extend You question? Tnx

Answer (score 0):

TestNG by default executes the tests in the order you mentioned in your testng xml file, unless if you are running the tests in parallel.

Quoting the [doc](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html):

> By default, TestNG will run your tests in the order they are found in
>   the XML file.

So, if your test is like:

```
<test name = "test1">
<test name = "test2">
<test name = "test3">
```

Then the order of the execution will be:

```
1) test1
2) test2
3) test3
```

Additionally, there is a parameter to control that : `preserve-order`. By default, it is true and if you set it to false, tests will be run randomly.

Comment: I have done this by: 1. creating an XML file in the project, 2. adding different classes with 'packagename.classname'. 3. Running this XML file as test suite. Thanks for your response to my question@ShivamMishra @Kovacic